# split neural network in two nets preserving weights in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In `keras` I would like to use the model with the initial layers of the structure for a given trained neuralnet with the weights I got for the training process.

Going to the case: Lets imagine we have a dataset `df`, after spliting into `train`, `dev` and `test`  we train a neural network, for this example an `autoencoder`.

A real piece of code illustrating this concept, without providing data(i didn't consider it necessary):

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input

# Define input layer
input_data = Input(shape=(train.shape[1],), name='Input')

# Define encoding layer
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_data)

# Define decoding layer
decoded = Dense(train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# Create the autoencoder model
autoencoder = Model(input_data, decoded, name='Simple AutoEncoder')

#Compile the autoencoder model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                    loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(train, train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(dev_x, dev_x), verbose=0)
```

After `compile` and `fit` the model we have a neural network with their weights that we got from fitting process.

How could I use only the `encoder part` of this net by preserving the weight I got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By training an `Autoencoder`, the `encoder` neuralnet part would be created with the encoded object that contains the trained weights of the autoencoder.

```
# Getting the trained weights of the first layer(dense layer of encoder)
weights_ae = autoencoder.layers[1].get_weights()[0]

# The previous code of the example...

# Creating the encoder model
encoder = Model(input_data, encoded, name='Encoder')

# Getting the weights of the encoder model
weights_e = encoder.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
```

So, finally it would be confirmed that by creating the model `encoder` would have the weights ("trainied experience") from the autoencoder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something along this line should do the trick:

```py
#...all the code from above, including training...

# Define the encoder model
encoder = Model(input_data, encoded, name='Encoder')
```

The `encoder` model can be treated as a fully-fledged Keras model (you can save/load/fit/evaluate/predict).

Comment: But if an "encoder" was instantiated after autoencoder.fit, it would not be trained and therefore would have random weights. Right?

Comment: I answered it as I expected to check if there was a "transference" of weights from the training process, this is not explained in most of tutorial doing Autoencoders.

Comment: Answering your question, no! If the encoder is instantiated after training the autoencoder, the encoder will get the status of the tensors included in his piece of graph. If the tensors weren't created yet (not the case), they would be initialized when creating the model. Since the tensors are already created, their internal values won't change.